How to do my own calculation of the line height of a specific font that has a certain size?
I want to manually calculate the line spacing of a certain font face given its size in points.
Trying to determine font's height I got a confusing result.
Having a font size of 12 points after measurement done in the PHP code bellow, I obtained my font's height as being of 10.5 points.
The code is simple, my assumption was that the height of a font is given by difference between a upper cased character like "X" and a lower cased descending one like "g".
How can I determine a line height for a font of a certain size?
<?php
// Font file path
$fontFile = './DejaVuSans.ttf';

// Font size in points
$fontSize = 12;

// Create an image with a background color
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(1, 1);
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $color);

$dpi = imageresolution($image);
// Set the font and size
$bbox_g = imagefttext($image, $fontSize, 0, 0, 0, $color, $fontFile, 'g');
$bbox_X = imagefttext($image, $fontSize, 0, 0, 0, $color, $fontFile, 'X');

// Calculate the line height/line spacing
$line_height_x = $bbox_g[1] - $bbox_g[7] ;
$line_height_X = $bbox_X[1] - $bbox_X[7] ;
$line_height = $bbox_g[1] - $bbox_X[7] ;
$lineHeightPoints = $line_height / $dpi[1] * 72;

// Output the line height
echo "Line height: $line_height pixels";
echo "Line height: $lineHeightPoints points";


// Free up memory
imagedestroy($image);
?>


By line height you mean the maximum height of a font as defined internally by it's ascender and descender records? Or do you mean a tight bounding box (stripping all empty space above and below letters)? For an approximation of the maximum height you may measure the bbox using the | pipe character

Yes, I am interested in the maximum height as defined by ascender and descender records.

Frankly, I think you should rather opt for javaScript font parsing libraries auch as opentype.js (including canvas and svg rendering capabilities) or lib.font (data only but usually the more up-to-date when it comes to newer open-type feature data records. Also deployed in the excellent font inspector wakamaifondue).

Sorry I know you have asked for a php solution, but php's  imagefttext is imho quite "underwhelming". The aforementioned JS options  will provide options for more fine-grained data retrieval options: UPM, Ascender, descender, left/right sidebearings, tight bounding boxes depending on letters – not to speak about better support for webfonts.
